# Drupal Bootstrap Template Hooks

Tags: theming

Inside the **template.php** I have this function:

```
function bootstrap_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    bootstrap_include($theme, 'theme/registry.inc');

    return _bootstrap_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);
}
```

I'm doing a migration from an old Drupal which has **$hooks** inside, and I need to move these hooks to my **bootstrap_theme**, the **$hooks** are these ones:

```
    $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
     'render element' => 'form',
    );
    $hooks['block__system__user_menu'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-menu-block',

    );
    $hooks['user_register'] = array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-register',
    );

     $hooks['user_pass'] = array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-pass',
    );
return $hooks;
```

How can I mix them without using a **sub_theme boostrap**

Comment: Couldn't you just merge the arrays before `return _bootstrap_theme`? Or do you mean without altering that code?

Comment: I tried:  
    array(_bootstrap_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path), $hooks);
It didn't work